# How Soap Service Handles Multiple Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, soap

I have an Apigee proxy that calls soap service that queries the database using customer id and it will return details associated on it. My question is what is the right way to construct it on a soap message request? Is it this

```html
<soap:Body>
     <v1:getCustomerInfobyIDRequest>
       <CustomerID>{CustomerIDs}</CustomerID>
     </v1:getCustomerInfobyIDRequest>
 </soap:Body>
```

Where CustomerIDs = 1,2,3,4 or this?

```html
<soap:Body>
   <v1:getCustomerInfobyIDRequest>
     <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
     <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
     <CustomerID>3</CustomerID>
     <CustomerID>4</CustomerID>
   </v1:getCustomerInfobyIDRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: The SOAP service WSDL should contain an XML Schema that describes how to construct the request. Are you able to add that to your question?